# Can I use coated ink jet paper for printing with a color laser printer?

Tags: printer, laser-printer, paper

Can I use coated ink jet paper for printing with a color laser printer? Or does this destroy the laser printer somehow?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It depends on the coating, but in general no.  Laser printers use heat to fix the toner to the paper.  It is quite possible for the coating on the paper to melt, destroying the printer.  Unless the paper explicitly says it will work with a laser printer, best to just avoid it.

Comment: Usually, the inkjet only paper will jam in the fuser. Most printers allow you to remove this part and clean it, but depending on the fuser and the paper used, you could jam something in there in a way you can't clear it out. Some fuser replacements can cost more then a new printer. The only way to actually destroy a printer is if the paper has a flammable coating that will actually catch fire when it goes through the fuser. That is extremely rare and I doubt you have to worry about it. All that being said, @KeithB is right, just avoid non-laser paper and you'll be fine.